# Unable to display list using spinner

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to create a simple dropdown spinner but the items  does not show up when I click the spinner.

Here is my main_activity code

````
```
var spinner =findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.snippet)
val adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.list_units,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
    )
    spinner1.adapter=adapter
````

```
    This is my Resource file
```

```
<array name="list_units">
    Feet
    Meters
    Cms
</array>
```

```
This is my xml file
```

````
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/snippet"/>
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should define your array in ...values like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="string_array_name">
        <item
            >text_string</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then import that array as string array, like this.

```
val values = resource.getStringArray(R.array.name_of_string_array)
```

and set above `values` array to your array adapter.

Comment: it worked I was missing the item